# How to convert result set to json records in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Say I have a table `my_table`:

```
select * from my_table;
```

returns:

| k1 | k2 | k3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | v2 | v3 |
| v4 | v5 | v6 |

I want to run a query on `my_table` and get:

| input |
| --- |
| {"k1" : "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3"} |
| {"k1" : "v4", "k2": "v5", "k3": "v6"} |

Is it possible with Redshift?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with

```
SELECT 
'{' ||
    '"k1": "' || k1 || '",'
    '"k2": "' || k2 || '",'
    '"k3": "' || k3 || '"'
'}' 
                        

from my_table

;
```

I wonder if there is a nicer way to do it